# Distribute amount monthly with respect to start date and end date

Tags: sql, database, advanced-queuing

I have table as

```
Project_ID
Start_Date
End_Date
BUDGET_Amount
```

For example:

I Need to Return with SQL 12 Row Each Row Represent the Month-Year between the Two Date and the Value of Budget = 1200 / No of months between two dates "12" = 100$

So The  Result to be like this 
     Proj_ID , START_DATE , END_DATE , AMOUNT

- "1","1-JAN-2017","31-JAN-2017",100$
- "1","1-FEB-2017","27-FEB-2017",100$m
- "1","1-MAR-2017","31-MAR-2017",100$
- "1","1-APR-2017","31-APR-2017",100$
- "1","1-MAY-2017","31-MAY-2017",100$
- "1","1-JUN-2017","31-JUN-2017",100$
- "1","1-JUL-2017","31-JUL-2017",100$
- "1","1-AUG-2017","31-AUG-2017",100$
- "1","1-SEP-2017","31-SEP-2017",100$
- "1","1-OCT-2017","31-OCT-2017",100$
- "1","1-NOV-2017","31-NOV-2017",100$
- "1","1-DEC-2017","31-DEC-2017",100$

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags. Please tag with the database you are really using . . . Oracle or SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

Using Common Table Expression(CTE) you can generate dates in given range. This will generate the output you need:

```
;with mycte as
     (
    select cast('1 jan 2017' as datetime) as DateValue
    union all
    select DATEADD(MONTH,1, DateValue)
    from    mycte  
    where   DATEADD(MONTH,1, DateValue) <= '31 dec 2017'
    )

   select 
   1 Proj_ID,
   REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), DateValue, 106), ' ', '-')  START_DATE ,
   REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(MONTH,1, DateValue))), ' ', '-')   END_DATE  ,
   '100$' AMOUNT
   from    mycte
```

This is will display months' first and last days.

Comment: It Need to be More Dynamic

Comment: It needs more explanation.

Comment: PROJECT_ID   START_DATE END_DATE REVENUE
30001            4/1/2016            4/1/2018         24,000
30002            4/1/2016            4/1/2018   2000
30003            1/1/2016            1/1/2017   5000

Comment: @MohamedFouad, Post a formatted data. May be screenshot ? For desired output.